# How to share common `buildscript` Gradle code?

Tags: gradle

I have some common build code. Much of it can be refactored into a `common.gradle` file and those that need the code can do something like:

```
apply from: "${rootDir}/common.gradle"
```

This works for most everything except code inside a `buildscript` block. How can that code be refactored and so that it can be reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way Gradle parses the build files, the `buildscript` block itself cannot be extracted and reused. All is not lost, however, since what's inside the `buildscript` block can be extracted and reused:

```
buildscript { scriptHandler ->
  apply from: "${rootDir}/common-buildscript.gradle", to: scriptHandler
}
```